# After Drag and Drop D3 TreeView control Zooming starts with the initial position

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have faced the below issue when we try to zoom the tree view control after dragging and dropping it into some other location of the HTML body it goes to the initial position and performed zooming. Can you please advise me to zoom the tee-view in the drag and drop location itself? I have attached the sample for your reference.

```js
var treeData =
  {
    "name": "Root",
    "children": [
      { 
        "name": "Item 1",
        "children": [
          { "name": "Item 3" },
          { "name": "Item 4" }
        ]
      },
      { 
        "name": "Item 2",
        "children": [
          { "name": "Item 5" },
          { "name": "Item 6" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 1520 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 705 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

function dragged(d) {
    debugger;
    var test = d3.select(this).attr("transform");
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", 'translate(' + (d3.event.sourceEvent.screenX - 400) + ',' + (d3.event.sourceEvent.screenY - 400) + ') ' + test.slice(test.indexOf('scale(')));
}

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("#TreeView").append("svg")
    .attr("id", ("D3TreeViewSvg"))
    .attr("width", 1520)
    .attr("height", 705)
    .attr("style", "margin: auto;display: block;overflow: visible;")
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "D3TreeViewG")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+ margin.left + "," + margin.top + ") scale(0.99)")
    .call(d3.drag().on("drag", dragged))
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        debugger;
        svg.attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.transform.x + ',' + d3.event.transform.y + ') scale(' + d3.event.transform.k + ')');
    }));
          
    var rect = svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("pointer-events", "all");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
//root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}
setTimeout(function(){
        $('#' + 'D3TreeViewSvg').css('width', (($(".D3TreeViewG")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width) + 'px'));
    }, 1000);
function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="TreeViewParent" style="height:705px;width:1520px;">
<div id="TreeView" style="height:100%;width:100%;"></div>
</div>
```